# Quickest way to find the difference in two meshes

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d

So I have a project where I am animating a head by morphing meshes.

I have one mesh I called 'current' which is the one that is operated on and eventually gets displayed on the screen. Then I have a load of morph targets which can be in effect partly and in combination with one another depending on their weight.

In my code I have to find the difference between the 3D points in the current mesh and whatever it is being morphed to.

I do that by looping over the positions in both meshes to find the difference in the points. So my calculation for the differences in X, Y and Z points is like this :

```
double xDif = morphMesh.Positions[loop].X - currentMesh.Positions[loop].X;
double yDif = morphMesh.Positions[loop].Y - currentMesh.Positions[loop].Y;
double zDif = morphMesh.Positions[loop].Z - currentMesh.Positions[loop].Z;
```

Say the mesh has 1000 positions which is about the most I use at the moment. That means 1000 calculations x 3. My question is whether there is a better way to perform that calculation ?

For example is there a way to do this in psuedocode :

```
myDifferences = morphMesh.Positions - currentMesh.Positions
```

In other words is there anything in C# with WPF to do that faster ?

I'm looking at OpenCL too, but have yet to get that working right.

Many thanks !

Comment: .NET doesn't always do the best with removing common sub-expressions. Putting `morphMesh.Positions[loop]` and `currentMesh.Positions[loop]` into a variable might help somewhat, especially if in a tight loop.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. Do you think if I moved the maths to a DLL it would work any quicker too ?

Comment: it should be possible to calculate only one diff as a distance between the points... `diff = (morpMesh.Positions[loop]-currentMesh.Positions[loop]).Lenght;` it would create a vector between those two points and returns its length and it might be (or might be not) faster then what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't get that to work. It returns a double rather than the Point3D that I need :/

Comment: Actually after some toying I got that to work like you said using : Vector3D foo = (morphMesh - currentMesh). Unfortunately I have to report that it takes the same amount of time. Oh well thanks for the thought :)